# How to populate a lstbox from a ,txt file at startup

Tags: c#, listbox, startup

I need to populate a listbox from a text file at startup. I also need to have the firt 2 lines eliminated from the listbox along with all blank lines, but that isn't to important right now. I am currently stuck at getting the listbox populated at all. Here is my code so far:

```
struct CDCLocationEntry
{
    public string name;
}

public partial class StartupForm : Form
{
    private List<CDCLocationEntry> CDCList = new List<CDCLocationEntry>();

    public StartupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line;

            CDCLocationEntry entry = new CDCLocationEntry();

            inputFile = File.OpenText("P3S1 Data File For Import.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                CDCList.Add(entry);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayText()
    {
        foreach (CDCLocationEntry entry in CDCList)
        {
            CDCLocationListBox.Items.Add(entry.name);
        }
    }

    private void StartupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadFile();

        DisplayText();
    }
```

visual studio is say my problem is here:

struct CDCLocationEntry
    {
        public string name;
    }

the message I'm getting is:

> Warning   1   Field 'Project_3___Section_1.CDCLocationEntry.name' is never
>   assigned to, and will always have its default value null

none of my notes or online help is giving me an answer for this.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems you're reading a line of text from your file but doing nothing with it. Effectively, you're adding an empty CDCLocationEntry to your list with no information from the line. What's more is you're adding the same instance for every line of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `CDCLocationEntry` instance inside the loop and assign, at this instance property `name`, the line coming from your file

```
inputFile = File.OpenText("P3S1 Data File For Import.txt");
while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
{
    CDCLocationEntry entry = new CDCLocationEntry();
    entry.name = inputFile.ReadLine();
    CDCList.Add(entry);
}
```

Your actual code creates just one instance of `CDCLocationEntry` outside the loop and, without assigning anything to the `name` property, adds this same instance in every loop.

Comment: That did it, thank you, I will mark this correct when the site allows me too.